# Dependency error on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had use ruby `2.1.4` version using `rvm` but whenever I tried to run `bundle install` on application it gives an error as given below

```
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.7, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

The first question is I switched ruby version to `2.1.4` then why should they give version `1.9.1` in error?

And the second question is, in application Gemfile there is dependent gem

```
    gem 'quality-measure-engine', :git => 'https://github.com/pophealth/quality-measure-engine.git', :branch => 'master'
```

due to dependent gem, this error occurs?

Comment: What do you get when you type the following commands: **rvm list** and **ruby -v** and **rvm gemset list**?

Comment: 'rvm list' and 'ruby -v' shows only '2.1.4' version. but before I install 'rvm' '2.1.4' version default ruby version was '1.9.1'.

Comment: Do you have a gemset created? **rvm gemset list**. Do you have .ruby-version or .rvmrc? If so check that it refers to ruby 2.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `bundle update`?

It will update the gem versions and dependencies in your `Gemfile.lock`.

See the docs [here](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html).

Comment: Ok, I will try it once again.